# React-native: Translation with i18n How to get fallback value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, translation

How to get the fallback variable ? (like en, fr, nl, es)

It is possible to do that ?

Comment: I know I can do that with a dirty way but I want to do that with a proper way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of the fallbacks value with the following way:

```
I18n.locales.get('en-EN');
```

For example this code returns :["en-EN", "en"]